# How to find the parent page <form> name from a user control in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-1.1

I have an asp.net webpage and I am rendering an user control with in it. I need to find the parent page form tag name in the user control code behind. My web project is in net 1.1 and I am using c# as the code behind language. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use at least .NET 2.0 following should work:

You can get the page from the `UserControl` via the `Page`-property of `Control`:

```
Page page = this.Page;
```

You get the `Form` via [`Page.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = page.Form;
String formName = form.Name;
```

In your case(ASP.NET 1.1) you need to give the form an ID and make it `runat=server`:

```
<form id="ServerForm" runat="server">
```

Codebehind or designer.cs-file:

```
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm ServerForm;
```

Now you can access it on serverside via ID:

Then you can access the [`HtmlForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform_properties%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and use it's `Name` property:

```
String formName = ServerForm.Name;
```

If you need to access it from the `UserControl` you could provide a public property in the `Page` and cast `this.Page` to the actual type, then you can access the property:

```
public HtmlForm Form 
{ 
    get { return ServerForm; }
}
```

or even better, just expose the name of the form:

```
public string FormName
{ 
    get { return ServerForm.Name; }
}
```